# add touch event on drawing items in drawRect

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, drawrect

I'm making a calendar app. Now I draw my appointment in the screen like this.

```
if (boolMark) {
        UIColor *blueColorMark = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.62 blue:.984 alpha:0.5];
        appointmentRect.origin.x += 5;
        appointmentRect.size.width -= 10;
        NSArray *appointments = [[mark valueForKey:@"appointments"] mutableCopy];
        float lblHeight = appointmentRect.origin.y - tileHeightAdjustment + 20;
        for (NSDictionary *appointment in appointments){
            UIImage *overlayImage=[self imageWithColor:blueColorMark];
            NSString *strTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[appointment valueForKey:@"app_label"]];
            if (forIpad) {
                NSLog(@"AppointmentRect Y = %f",lblHeight);
                appointmentRect.origin.y = lblHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                appointmentRect.origin.y -= 6;
            }
            appointmentRect.size.height = [self calculateHeight:strTitle andWidth:appointmentRect.size.width];
            lblHeight += appointmentRect.size.height + 5;

            [overlayImage drawInRect:appointmentRect];
            UIFont *f3 =[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:10];
            [strTitle drawInRect: appointmentRect
                   withFont: f3
              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
                  alignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];


        }
    }
```

Now I want when a user touches a certain appointment show a detailView with more information about the appointment.

My question now, is how to set an action when a user taps a certain appointment (certain overlayImage)?

Any help?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

It would be easier for you if you parsed your appointments to a model class `Appointment`. 
before you draw each appointment, make a calculation of each appointment view's rect and then you could store that data in an array of dictionaries for later, something like this

```
@[@{@"appointmentKey" : appointmentObject1, @"frameKey" : [NSValue valueWithCGRect:calculatedRect1]},
  @{@"appointmentKey" : appointmentObject2, @"frameKey" : [NSValue valueWithCGRect:calculatedRect2]}];
```

- you will use this later for drawing and finding the correct appointment.
- make a method `Appointment* appointmentForPoint:(CGPoint point)`, which iterates all the dictionaries in the upper array and checks `CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)`; if true, return an appointment associated with that dictionary.
- add a tap gesture recognizer to the view and call `appointmentForPoint:` to get the correct appointment.